# How to find non-existing data from another Table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables groups and contact and i fetch all groups with their total number of contact in contact table. Like in groups table i have values

```
  group1
  group2
```

in contact table i have

```
  myname group1
  myname1 group1
  myname2 group1
```

now i want all groupname with their contact count like

```
  group1 3
  group2 0
```

i used :

```
SELECT g.gid,g.groupname,g.TYPE,g.DATE,COUNT(*)AS cnt,1 
FROM groupname g,contacts c 
WHERE g.gid=c.gid AND uid=1 GROUP BY groupname
```

But i got those group which have value.

Answer (score 1):

use `Left Outer Join` instead of old style of `Inner Join`

```
SELECT g.groupname,
       Count(c.gid) as Cnt
FROM   groups g
       LEFT OUTER JOIN contact c
                    ON g.gid = c.gid
WHERE  uid = 1
GROUP  BY g.groupname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT g.gid, g.groupname, g.TYPE, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM contacts c
        WHERE c.gid = g.gid) AS cnt
FROM groupname g
WHERE  uid=1
```

Comment: if we have 10K records, then above sub query will execute for 10K times..!

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia: currently the table contains two records ;) I'm more familiar with SQL-Server where this is not an issue.

Comment: but I think it is just for question understanding purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.gid,g.groupname,g.TYPE,g.DATE,COUNT(*)AS cnt,1 
FROM groupname g 
LEFT JOIN contacts c on c.group_name = g.group_name 
WHERE g.gid=c.gid AND uid=1 GROUP BY groupname
```